# CKEDITOR How do I send HTML data via json

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, ckeditor

I am trying to save my CKEDITOR data back to my CMS via ajax/json. However if there is binary inlined in the data (e.g. pasted image) the ajax fails. It seems I have trouble with special characters like \, ", etc.

I cannot find an encode/escape method that works which will escape all the HTML from the CKEditor.getData before I submit it via json.

The code below works fine as long as I dont put \ (backslash) or paste an image into the CKEditor.

```
<div id="content" contenteditable=true>
   ... sample content...
</div>
<script>

CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = false;

var editor = CKEDITOR.inline( 'content', {
    on: {
        instanceReady: function() {
            periodicData();
        }
    }
} );

var periodicData = ( function(){
    var data, oldData;
    return function() {
        if ( ( data = editor.getData() ) !== oldData ) {
            oldData = data;
            store(data);
        }

        setTimeout( periodicData, 1000 );
    };

})();

function store(data) {

newData = '{ "entry" : { "name" : "Body", "type" : "HTMLComponent", "content" : { "type" : "text/html", "value" : "'+data+'" } } }';

$.ajax({
    type: 'put',
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {"contentType": "application/json", "Accept" : "application/json"},
    url: url,
    data: newData
});
}

</script>
```

Comment: And we can't really help you without seeing your code...

Comment: I have now added the code above. How do I properly escape the "data" so allow backslash, quote, and binary representations?

Comment: Just use `JSON.stringify(rawjson)` to turn your json into a string; don't ever hand-code it yourself, or you'll run into problems.  `rawjson` in that example is something like `{entry: {name: "body"}}`; notice the lack of single quotes?  Moreover; you don't even need to stringify json passed to jquery's ajax function; it accepts raw json normally.